# PHP Decimal to base64 give different result with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

can someone tell me why fo base64 result give different result for PHP

with Javascript that's give right result

decimal 68 98 7 will show RGIH
https://v2.cryptii.com/decimal/base64
[javascript decimal to base64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brHEB.png)

why on php i not see same result

with this code

`$x = floatval('68 98 7'); echo base64_encode($x);`

will show Njg=

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because the website you've posted doesn't interpret the decimals as decimals, but as the decimal values for their ASCII counterparts. If you want to perform the same operation in PHP, you could first transform the decimal string to an array by exploding on the spaces, applying `chr` to each entry of the array, and then base64 encoding the imploded array:

```php
$decimals = '68 98 7';
$chars = array_map(fn($decimal) => chr((int)$decimal), explode(' ',$decimals));
echo base64_encode(implode('', $chars));
```